# In java map, I want to assign the repository functions as value like Map<key, function(>

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashmap

I Want to call the JPA repository functions to access the data from the database based on the String value passed.

So I want to make the string as the key and the reposetory function as Value so that I could call the function like:

```
 map.set("id":repository.findById())
map.set("name":repository.findByName())
```

To access the result I just  pass the string(str) value as "id" or "name" and get the result.
call map.get(str);

I got a solution [Maps : In Java Maps can I assign a function to the value in the <K,V> pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610041/maps-in-java-maps-can-i-assign-a-function-to-the-value-in-the-k-v-pair), But it's looking old approach, do we have any other new/better approach...?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: What is the type of the map's key and value?